# Google Text-To-Speech API

Tags: text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I want to know how can I use Google Text-to-Speech API in my .NET project. I think I need to call a URL to use the web service, but the idea for me is not clear. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is any official API?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053442/google-translate-tts-api-blocked

Comment: This one works for me https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS

Comment: There's an official API now - see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75452238/5050285

Answer (score 65):

Old answer:

*Try using this URL:
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20World
It will automatically generate a wav file which you can easily get with an HTTP request through any .net programming.*

Edit:

Ohh Google, you thought you could prevent people from using your wonderful service with flimsy http header verification.

Here is a solution to get a response in multiple languages (I'll try to add more as we go):

**NodeJS**

```
// npm install `request`
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const text = 'Hello World';

const options = {
    url: `https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=${encodeURIComponent(text)}&tl=en&client=tw-ob`,
    headers: {
        'Referer': 'http://translate.google.com/',
        'User-Agent': 'stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)'
    }
}

request(options)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('tts.mp3'))
```

---

**Curl**

```
curl 'https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Hello%20Everyone&tl=en&client=tw-ob' -H 'Referer: http://translate.google.com/' -H 'User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)' > google_tts.mp3
```

Note that the headers are based on @Chris Cirefice's example, if they stop working at some point I'll attempt to recreate conditions for this code to function. All credits for the current headers go to him and the wonderful tool that is WireShark. (also thanks to Google for not patching this)

Comment: The link above is broken. The Google Translate API docs are at https://developers.google.com/translate/.

Comment: Try this http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20World
Apparently there is a problem with referring the link from Stackoverflow but I tried it with HTTP request through JS and used it with HTML5 sound api, works fine!

Comment: It works if you try it in an incognito browser session, so yes, there shouldn't be a referer header in the request.

Comment: Are there any rate limits to the above URL?

Comment: If you want to use it with `wget` or `curl`, setting the User-agent header to an empty string seems to work fine.

Comment: It certainly does! Although it's very limited. I would advice to purchase the service from Google or use a third-party TTS service. As for .Net projects it's rather not too difficult to implement good TTS services although they would not outweigh Google's expertise in the field.

Comment: It works when I tried playing it using Chrome. However, it doesn't seem to work when I tried to use the url as an [html5 audio source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp). The web service might be considering the http referrer header.

Comment: Google has implemented abuse protection, so this URL now redirects to a CAPTCHA page. To get around this, see [my answer-as-an-update](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31791632/1986871).

Answer (score 49):

In an update to [Schahriar SaffarShargh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054006/1986871), Google has recently implemented a 'Google abuse' feature, making it impossible to send just any regular old HTTP GET to a URL such as:

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20World

which worked just fine and dandy previously. Now, following such a link presents you with a CAPTCHA. This also affects HTTP GET requests out-of-browser (such as with cURL), because using that URL gives a redirect to the abuse protection page (the CAPTCHA).

To start, you have to add the query parameter `client` to the request URL:

`http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20World&client=t`

Google Translate sends `&client=t`, so you should too.

Before you make that HTTP request, make sure that you set the `Referer` header:

`Referer: http://translate.google.com/`

Evidently, the `User-Agent` header is also required, but interestingly enough it can be blank:

`User-Agent:`

**Edit**: ***NOTE*** - on some user-agents, such as Android 4.X, the **custom** `User-Agent` header is *not sent*, meaning that Google will not service the request. In order to solve that problem, I simply set the `User-Agent` to a valid one, such as `stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)`. Use **Wireshark** to debug requests (as I did) if Google's servers are not responding, and ensure that these headers are being set properly in the `GET`! Google will respond with a `503 Service Unavailable` if the request fails, followed by a redirect to the CAPTCHA page.

This solution is a bit brittle; it is entirely possible that Google will change the way they handle these requests in the future, so in the end I would suggest asking Google to make a *real* API endpoint (free or paid) that we can use without feeling dirty for faking HTTP headers.

---

**Edit 2**: For those interested, this cURL command should work perfectly fine to download an mp3 of *Hello* in English:

```
curl 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Hello&tl=en&client=t' -H 'Referer: http://translate.google.com/' -H 'User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)' > google_tts.mp3
```

As you may notice, I have set both the `Referer` and `User-Agent` headers in the request, as well as added the `client=t` parameter to the querystring. You may use `https` instead of `http`, your choice!

---

**Edit 3**: Google now requires a token for each GET request (noted by `tk` in the querystring). Below is the revised cURL command that will correctly download a TTS mp3:

`curl 'https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=hello&tl=en&tk=995126.592330&client=t' -H 'user-agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)' -H 'referer: https://translate.google.com/' > google_tts.mp3`

Notice the **&tk=995126.592330** in the querystring; this is the new token. I obtained this token by pressing the speaker icon on `translate.google.com` and looking at the GET request. I simply added this querystring parameter to the previous cURL command, and it works.

***NOTE***: obviously this solution is very frail, and breaks at the whim of the architects at Google who introduce new things like tokens required for the requests. This token may not work tomorrow (though I will check and report back)... the point is, it is not wise to rely on this method; instead, one should turn to a commercial TTS solution, especially if using TTS in production.

For further explanation of the token generation and what you might be able to do about it, see [Boude's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34687566/1986871).

---

If this solution breaks any time in the future, please leave a comment on this answer so that we can attempt to find a fix for it!

Comment: I've tried adding Referer header(with CURL), but it still redirects to Capctha page. Could you provide some script which worked for you? Thanks!

Comment: @Syom See my edit :) also, check Wireshark or some other network analysis tool to ensure that the headers are being sent properly. As I mentioned in my answer, some devices may strip out custom headers, or do something else that is undesirable causing the request to fail.

Comment: That works. Thank you very much!
In general, Referer is not required. It jus need the User-Agent header!
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)');

Comment: @Syom Interesting, I wasn't able to get it to work without `Referer`... Well, one extra header 'just in case' isn't going to hurt now is it ;)

Comment: The curl command of edit2 still works to date and trust me it's only one of the few. Thanks so much.

Comment: @dr.doom Glad to know that I was of help :)

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Just curious; with the curl version, is there a way to get it to be fed a text file instead of the "Hello" string?

Comment: @Akiva That's definitely possible as long as the language you're using can open files. You can use string concatenation to build the CURL command, or string substitution to replace the `q=XXXX` and `tl=XX` parts (which is preferred). Be aware that the *entire string must be URL-encoded*, otherwise spaces in the text query will cause timeouts. So `q=Hello world` must be encoded to `q=Hello%20world`.

Comment: Does this still work? I'm trying to write a PHP function that downloads an mp3 of a given word with curl. I briefly had it working once, but all I'm getting now is a 2KB mp3 file that doesn't play. I'm basically getting "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network" despite using `curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)' );` Any suggestions?

Comment: @juliusbangert You're setting the *user-agent* header correctly, but is your *querystring* correct? It should look like this: `http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Hello&tl=en&client=t`. The inportant part is `client=t`; without that, the request will be blocked. You *may* also need to set the *referer* header to `http://translate.google.com/`.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice I had `client=t` but not `ie=UTF-8` in the querystring. Either way it's not working for me. I've also tried `http` and `https`. But I'm just getting "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network". Is there any other `curl_setopt` I should be doing for this or is it possible that google have totally blocked this now?

Comment: @juliusbangert Can you post a new question and reply here with a link to it? Comments aren't really a good place for debugging. I can confirm however that the TTS request works, so there must be something missing in your code.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Thanks, do you think there is a request limit? Like after a few requests it stops working? I was able to make it work a few times but then it goes back to the 2KB non-playable mp3. I've posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134304/using-google-text-to-speech-api-to-save-speech-audio

Comment: It did work - but since somewhere last month it doesn't anmymore. It looks like the translation service now creates a token that you must send along, otherwise you get empty responses (check the URL used when using TTS, you can see the new "tk" parameter. I'm going to find a way to work around this..

Comment: Fixed :) See my new answer.

Comment: @RobQuist I did a bit more debugging, and yes you are correct in that Google added a `tk` parameter to the URL. After inspecting the GET request used by the speaker icon on `translate.google.com`, it generates a valid token that you can use in the cURL command. I'm not sure if these tokens expire... I'll try the cURL command tomorrow and again in a week to see if it's still valid. The problem is that this is still a fragile solution... so obviously moving to a commercial TTS service is the best option over time! I edited my answer with a cURL command that actually works (includes a token).

Comment: @boude You suggested an edit which shows the code used to generate the new token. However, that code doesn't really belong in my answer, but would be useful as an *additional* answer. Would you mind posting an answer with your code and link back to my answer for context? I think that would be the most useful.

Comment: It seems to work without token if you set the 'client' parameter to 'tw-ob', but this will probably change in the future. You have to also use HTTPS and set the 'User-Agent' header.

Comment: @DAN it works with 'tw-ob' and without 'tk'. But from where did you find 'tw-ob' ?!

Comment: @Babak: I've found it on StackOverflow, but I don't have the link anymore.

Comment: This seems to be broken again. My code based on this post worked a few months back (around jan-feb '17) but is broken now (apr '17). Replacing client=t with client=tw-ob seems to do the trick though. Please verify and update the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Expanding on [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31791632/1017005). I managed to reverse engineer the token generation process.

The token for the request is based on the text and a global TKK variable set in the page script. These are hashed in JavaScript thus resulting in the tk param.

Somewhere in the page script you will find something like this:

`TKK='403413';`

This is the amount of hours passed since epoch.

The text is pumped in the following function (somewhat deobfuscated):

```js
var query = "Hello person";
var cM = function(a) {
    return function() {
        return a
    }
};
var of = "=";
var dM = function(a, b) {
    for (var c = 0; c < b.length - 2; c += 3) {
        var d = b.charAt(c + 2),
            d = d >= t ? d.charCodeAt(0) - 87 : Number(d),
            d = b.charAt(c + 1) == Tb ? a >>> d : a << d;
        a = b.charAt(c) == Tb ? a + d & 4294967295 : a ^ d
    }
    return a
};

var eM = null;
var cb = 0;
var k = "";
var Vb = "+-a^+6";
var Ub = "+-3^+b+-f";
var t = "a";
var Tb = "+";
var dd = ".";
var hoursBetween = Math.floor(Date.now() / 3600000);
window.TKK = hoursBetween.toString();

fM = function(a) {
    var b;
    if (null === eM) {
        var c = cM(String.fromCharCode(84)); // char 84 is T
        b = cM(String.fromCharCode(75)); // char 75 is K
        c = [c(), c()];
        c[1] = b();
        // So basically we're getting window.TKK
        eM = Number(window[c.join(b())]) || 0
    }
    b = eM;

    // This piece of code is used to convert d into the utf-8 encoding of a
    var d = cM(String.fromCharCode(116)),
        c = cM(String.fromCharCode(107)),
        d = [d(), d()];
    d[1] = c();
    for (var c = cb + d.join(k) +
            of, d = [], e = 0, f = 0; f < a.length; f++) {
        var g = a.charCodeAt(f);

        128 > g ? d[e++] = g : (2048 > g ? d[e++] = g >> 6 | 192 : (55296 == (g & 64512) && f + 1 < a.length && 56320 == (a.charCodeAt(f + 1) & 64512) ? (g = 65536 + ((g & 1023) << 10) + (a.charCodeAt(++f) & 1023), d[e++] = g >> 18 | 240, d[e++] = g >> 12 & 63 | 128) : d[e++] = g >> 12 | 224, d[e++] = g >> 6 & 63 | 128), d[e++] = g & 63 | 128)
    }


    a = b || 0;
    for (e = 0; e < d.length; e++) a += d[e], a = dM(a, Vb);
    a = dM(a, Ub);
    0 > a && (a = (a & 2147483647) + 2147483648);
    a %= 1E6;
    return a.toString() + dd + (a ^ b)
};

var token = fM(query);
var url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q="  + encodeURI(query) + "&tl=en&total=1&idx=0&textlen=12&tk=" + token + "&client=t";
document.write(url);
```

<s>I managed to successfully port this to python in [my fork of gTTS](https://github.com/Boudewijn26/gTTS), so I know this works.</s>

Edit: By now the token generation code used by gTTS has been moved into [gTTS-token](https://github.com/Boudewijn26/gTTS-token).

Edit 2: Google has changed the API (somewhere around 2016-05-10), this method requires some modification. I'm currently working on this. [In the meantime changing the client to tw-ob seems to work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053442/google-translate-tts-api-blocked)

Edit 3:

The changes are minor, yet annoying to say the least. The TKK now has two parts. Looking something like `406986.2817744745`. As you can see the first part has remained the same. The second part is the sum of two seemingly random numbers. `TKK=eval('((function(){var a\x3d2680116022;var b\x3d137628723;return 406986+\x27.\x27+(a+b)})())');` Here `\x3d` means `=` and `\x27` is `'`. Both a and b change every UTC minute. At one of the final steps in the algorithm the token is XORed by the second part.

The new token generation code is:

```js
var xr = function(a) {
    return function() {
        return a
    }
};
var yr = function(a, b) {
    for (var c = 0; c < b.length - 2; c += 3) {
        var d = b.charAt(c + 2)
          , d = "a" <= d ? d.charCodeAt(0) - 87 : Number(d)
          , d = "+" == b.charAt(c + 1) ? a >>> d : a << d;
        a = "+" == b.charAt(c) ? a + d & 4294967295 : a ^ d
    }
    return a
};
var zr = null;
var Ar = function(a) {
    var b;
    if (null  !== zr)
        b = zr;
    else {
        b = xr(String.fromCharCode(84));
        var c = xr(String.fromCharCode(75));
        b = [b(), b()];
        b[1] = c();
        b = (zr = window[b.join(c())] || "") || ""
    }
    var d = xr(String.fromCharCode(116))
      , c = xr(String.fromCharCode(107))
      , d = [d(), d()];
    d[1] = c();
    c = "&" + d.join("") + 
    "=";
    d = b.split(".");
    b = Number(d[0]) || 0;
    for (var e = [], f = 0, g = 0; g < a.length; g++) {
        var l = a.charCodeAt(g);
        128 > l ? e[f++] = l : (2048 > l ? e[f++] = l >> 6 | 192 : (55296 == (l & 64512) && g + 1 < a.length && 56320 == (a.charCodeAt(g + 1) & 64512) ? (l = 65536 + ((l & 1023) << 10) + (a.charCodeAt(++g) & 1023),
        e[f++] = l >> 18 | 240,
        e[f++] = l >> 12 & 63 | 128) : e[f++] = l >> 12 | 224,
        e[f++] = l >> 6 & 63 | 128),
        e[f++] = l & 63 | 128)
    }
    a = b;
    for (f = 0; f < e.length; f++)
        a += e[f],
        a = yr(a, "+-a^+6");
    a = yr(a, "+-3^+b+-f");
    a ^= Number(d[1]) || 0;
    0 > a && (a = (a & 2147483647) + 2147483648);
    a %= 1E6;
    return c + (a.toString() + "." + (a ^ b))
}
;
Ar("test");
```

Of course I can't generate a valid url anymore, since I don't know how a and b are generated.

Comment: Thanks for adding another answer, +1! I will edit my answer to point to yours for further explanation.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for this.

Comment: Google changed token structure again. Now this algorithm does not work.
Any new solutions?

Comment: @Syom [A simpler approach has always existed in changing the client to tw-ob.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32053452/1017005) I'm currently looking into the changes Google has made. They appear to be minor, yet they have expanded their seed with a random text which changes every minute. I'll report back once I know more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will be looking for possible solutions.

Comment: @Boude even without knowing how a and b are generated, ACQUIRING some TKK value is easy. TKK value changes every hour, but so far Google do not block "tk"s generated by old "tkk". even if they start requiring that you have the latest TKK, scraping it periodically from https://translate.google.com shouldn't be too hard...

Answer (score 12):

An additional alternative is: [responsivevoice.org](http://responsivevoice.org) a simple example JsFiddle is [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/keyaask6/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<input type="text" name="text">
<button id="gspeech" class="say">Say It</button>
<audio id="player1" src="" class="speech" hidden></audio>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#gspeech').on('click', function(){
        
        var text = $('input[name="text"]').val();
        responsiveVoice.speak("" + text +"");
        <!--  http://responsivevoice.org/ -->
    });

});
```

External Resource:

https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js

Comment: This actually works without having to hack or fear that something breaks.

Answer (score 7):

i have created this like : q= urlencode & tl = language name

Just try this :

https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%20%E0%A6%A4%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%BC%20%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B2%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BF+&tl=bn&client=tw-ob

Answer (score 6):

Allright, so Google has introduces tokens (see the tk parameter in the new url) and the old solution doesn't seem to work. I've found an alternative - which I even think is better-sounding, and has more voices! The command isn't pretty, but it works. Please note that this is for testing purposes only (I use it for a little domotica project) and use the real version from acapella-group if you're planning on using this commercially.

```
curl $(curl --data 'MyLanguages=sonid10&MySelectedVoice=Sharon&MyTextForTTS=Hello%20World&t=1&SendToVaaS=' 'http://www.acapela-group.com/demo-tts/DemoHTML5Form_V2.php' | grep -o "http.*mp3") > tts_output.mp3
```

Some of the supported voices are;

- Sharon
- Ella (genuine child voice)
- EmilioEnglish (genuine child voice)
- Josh (genuine child voice)
- Karen
- Kenny (artificial child voice)
- Laura
- Micah
- Nelly (artificial child voice)
- Rod
- Ryan
- Saul
- Scott (genuine teenager voice)
- Tracy
- ValeriaEnglish (genuine child voice)
- Will
- WillBadGuy (emotive voice)
- WillFromAfar (emotive voice)
- WillHappy (emotive voice)
- WillLittleCreature (emotive voice)
- WillOldMan (emotive voice)
- WillSad (emotive voice)
- WillUpClose (emotive voice)

It also supports multiple languages and more voices - for that I refer you to their website; http://www.acapela-group.com/

Comment: Hi,

Could you post how that can be used in php?

Comment: Just as @srik reported, this solution is broken and is still as of today. It looks like *The Acapela Group* removed this php file for direct access from their server(s).

Comment: Seems to be working again, but the acapela group have since added a background music to the tts, so it is a bit more distracting to use now. The quality is great though.

Answer (score 5):

You can download the Voice using Wget:D

```
wget -q -U Mozilla "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello"
```

Save the output into a mp3 file:

```
wget -q -U Mozilla "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello" -O hello.mp3
```

Enjoy !!

Answer (score 4):

Google text to speech

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function play(id){
            var text = document.getElementById(id).value;
            var url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q='+text;
            var a = new Audio(url);
                a.play();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="text" />
        <button onclick="play('text');"> Speak it </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20World

note the www.translate.google.com

Comment: Doing a wget using
wget http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20World

gives this error
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-08-30 14:43:26 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Comment: Guys, I am using TTS similar to this code.

"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello"

but I get good quality reply on pc while code run on android is really bad quality. Should I allow somethime to download the file?

Answer (score 3):

As of now, Google official Text-to-Speech service is available at https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/

It's free for the first 4 million characters.

Comment: Can I use it in a commercial Android app?

Comment: @August Yes. it's an official service provided by Google.

Answer (score 1):

I used the url as above: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20World

And requested with python library..however I'm getting `HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN`

In the end I had to mock the `User-Agent` header with the [browser's one](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `console.developer.google.com` login and get an API key
or use microsoft bing's API
 `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396`

or even better use AT&T's speech API `developer.att.com`(paid one)

For voice recognition

```
Public Class Voice_recognition

    Public Function convertTotext(ByVal path As String, ByVal output As String) As String
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=speech2text&lang=en-US&maxresults=10"), HttpWebRequest)
        'path = Application.StartupPath & "curinputtmp.mp3"
        request.Timeout = 60000
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.KeepAlive = True
        request.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=8000"  
        request.UserAgent = "speech2text"

        Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(path)
        Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length
        Dim data As Byte()

        Using fStream As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            data = New Byte(CInt(fStream.Length - 1)) {}
            fStream.Read(data, 0, CInt(fStream.Length))
            fStream.Close()
        End Using

        Using wrStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            wrStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        End Using

        Try
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Dim resp = response.GetResponseStream()

            If resp IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim sr As New StreamReader(resp)
                MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd())

                resp.Close()
                resp.Dispose()
            End If
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return 0
    End Function
End Class
```

And for text to speech: [use this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?676853-Google-speech-in-vbscript).

I think you'll understand this
if didn't then use vbscript to vb/C# converter.
still didn't then contact Me.

I have done this before ,can't find the code now that this why i'm not directly givin' you the code.

Answer (score 1):

Because it came up in chat here , and the first page for googeling was this one, i decided to let all in on my findings googling some more XD

you really dont need to go any length anymore to make it work simply stand on the shoulders of giants:

#### there is a standard

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/webspeechapi.html

#### and an example

http://html5-examples.craic.com/google_chrome_text_to_speech.html

at least for your web projects this should work (e.g. asp.net)

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def run(cmd):
    import os
    import sys
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    print(cmd)
    proc=Popen(cmd, stdin=None, stdout=PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
    while True:
        data = proc.stdout.readline()   # Alternatively proc.stdout.read(1024)
        if len(data) == 0:
            print("Finished process")
            break
        sys.stdout.write(data)

import urllib

msg='Hello preety world'
msg=urllib.quote_plus(msg)
# -v verbosity
cmd='curl '+ \
    '--output tts_responsivevoice.mp2 '+ \
    "\""+'https://code.responsivevoice.org/develop/getvoice.php?t='+msg+'&tl=en-US&sv=g2&vn=&pitch=0.5&rate=0.5&vol=1'+"\""+ \
    ' -H '+"\""+'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0'+"\""+ \
    ' -H '+"\""+'Accept: audio/webm,audio/ogg,audio/wav,audio/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,video/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5'+"\""+ \
    ' -H '+"\""+'Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3'+"\""+ \
    ' -H '+"\""+'Range: bytes=0-'+"\""+ \
    ' -H '+"\""+'Referer: http://code.responsivevoice.org/develop/examples/example2.html'+"\""+ \
    ' -H '+"\""+'Cookie: __cfduid=ac862i73b6a61bf50b66713fdb4d9f62c1454856476; _ga=GA1.2.2126195996.1454856480; _gat=1'+"\""+ \
    ' -H '+"\""+'Connection: keep-alive'+"\""+ \
    ''
print('***************************')
print(cmd)
print('***************************')
run(cmd)
```

Line:

```
/getvoice.php?t='+msg+'&tl=en-US&sv=g2&vn=&pitch=0.5&rate=0.5&vol=1'+"\""+ \
```

is responsible for language.

```
tl=en-US
```

There is another preety interesting site with tts engines that can be used in this manner.

substitute o for null
iv0na.c0m

have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

#### The 2023 Answer:

There's a Google Text to Speech Service in Google Cloud. It is an API service. To use it, you must first enable the Text-to-Speech API in Google Console.

Next, go to [APIs & Services > Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and create a new API Key (Create Credentials > API Key).

Finally, you can call the POST API endpoint `https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=[API KEY]`

```
{ "audioConfig": { "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16", "pitch": "0.00", "speakingRate": "1.00" }, "input": { "text": "Hello World" }, "voice": { "languageCode": "en-US", "name": "en-US-Wavenet-E" } }
```

Response:

```
{
    "audioContent": "UklGRr7CAABXQVZF..."
}
```

Comment: There's also a SDK for C# https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp