# How to capture generated audio from window.speechSynthesis.speak() call?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, text-to-speech, webspeech-api

Previous questions have presented this same or similar inquiry

- [Can Web Speech API used in conjunction with Web Audio API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902789/can-web-speech-api-used-in-conjunction-with-web-audio-api/)
- [How to access audio result from Speech Synthesis API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514588/how-to-access-audio-result-from-speech-synthesis-api?rq=1)
- [Record HTML5 SpeechSynthesisUtterance generated speech to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905583/record-html5-speechsynthesisutterance-generated-speech-to-file/30999808#30999808)
- [generate audio file with W3C Web Speech API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727696/generate-audio-file-with-w3c-web-speech-api?rq=1)

yet no workarounds appear to be have been created using `window.speechSynthesis()`. Though there are workarounds using `epeak` , `meSpeak` [How to create or convert text to audio at chromium browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346410/how-to-create-or-convert-text-to-audio-at-chromium-browser) or making requests to external servers.

How to capture and record audio output of `window.speechSynthesis.speak()` call and return result as a `Blob`, `ArrayBuffer`, `AudioBuffer` or other object type?

Answer (score 26):

The [Web Speech API Specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/webspeechapi.html) does not presently provide a means or hint on how to achieve returning or capturing and recording audio output of `window.speechSynthesis.speak()` call.

See also

- [MediaStream, ArrayBuffer, Blob audio result from speak() for recording?](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2017Jun/0000.html)
- [Re: MediaStream, ArrayBuffer, Blob audio result from speak() for recording?](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2017Jul/0001.html)
- [Re: MediaStream, ArrayBuffer, Blob audio result from speak() for recording?](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2017Jul/0004.html). In pertinent part, use cases include, but are not limited to

  1. Persons who have issues speaking; i.e.g., persons whom have suffered a
     stroke or other communication inhibiting afflictions. They could convert
     text to an audio file and send the file to another individual or group.
     This feature would go towards helping them communicate with other persons,
     similar to the technologies which assist Stephen Hawking communicate;
  2. Presently, the only person who can hear the audio output is the person
     in front of the browser; in essence, not utilizing the full potential of
     the text to speech functionality. The audio result can be used as an
     attachment within an email; media stream; chat system; or other
     communication application. That is, control over the generated audio output;
  3. Another application would be to provide a free, libre, open source audio
     dictionary and translation service - client to client and client to server,
     server to client.

It is possible to capture the output of audio output of `window.speechSynthesis.speak()` call utilizing `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` and `MediaRecorder()`. The expected result is returned at Chromium browser. Implementation at Firefox has [issues](https://github.com/guest271314/SpeechSynthesisRecorder/issues). Select `Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo` at `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` prompt.

The workaround is cumbersome. We should be able to get generated audio, at least as a `Blob`, without `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` and `MediaRecorder()`.

More interest is evidently necessary by users of browsers, JavaScript and C++ developers, browser implementers and specification authors for further input; to create a proper specification for the feature, and consistent implementation at browsers' source code; see [How to implement option to return Blob, ArrayBuffer, or AudioBuffer from window.speechSynthesis.speak() call](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/352073/how-to-implement-option-to-return-blob-arraybuffer-or-audiobuffer-from-window).

At Chromium a speech dispatcher program should be installed and the instance launched with `--enable-speech-dispatcher` flag set, as `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` returns an empty array, see [How to use Web Speech API at chromium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013933/how-to-use-web-speech-api-at-chromium).

Proof of concept

```
// SpeechSynthesisRecorder.js guest271314 6-17-2017
// Motivation: Get audio output from `window.speechSynthesis.speak()` call
// as `ArrayBuffer`, `AudioBuffer`, `Blob`, `MediaSource`, `MediaStream`, `ReadableStream`, or other object or data types
// See https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2017Jun/0000.html
// https://github.com/guest271314/SpeechSynthesisRecorder

// Configuration: Analog Stereo Duplex
// Input Devices: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo, Built-in Audio Analog Stereo

class SpeechSynthesisRecorder {
  constructor({text = "", utteranceOptions = {}, recorderOptions = {}, dataType = ""}) {
    if (text === "") throw new Error("no words to synthesize");
    this.dataType = dataType;
    this.text = text;
    this.mimeType = MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("audio/webm; codecs=opus") 
                    ? "audio/webm; codecs=opus" : "audio/ogg; codecs=opus";
    this.utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(this.text);
    this.speechSynthesis = window.speechSynthesis;
    this.mediaStream_ = new MediaStream();
    this.mediaSource_ = new MediaSource();
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.mediaStream_, {
      mimeType: this.mimeType,
      bitsPerSecond: 256 * 8 * 1024
    });
    this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
    this.audioNode = new Audio();
    this.chunks = Array();
    if (utteranceOptions) {
      if (utteranceOptions.voice) {
        this.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = e => {
          const voice = this.speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(({
            name: _name
          }) => _name === utteranceOptions.voice);
          this.utterance.voice = voice;
          console.log(voice, this.utterance);
        }
        this.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
      }
      let {
        lang, rate, pitch
      } = utteranceOptions;
      Object.assign(this.utterance, {
        lang, rate, pitch
      });
    }
    this.audioNode.controls = "controls";
    document.body.appendChild(this.audioNode);
  }
  start(text = "") {
    if (text) this.text = text;
    if (this.text === "") throw new Error("no words to synthesize");
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
      })
      .then(stream => new Promise(resolve => {
        const track = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
        this.mediaStream_.addTrack(track);
        // return the current `MediaStream`
        if (this.dataType && this.dataType === "mediaStream") {
          resolve({tts:this, data:this.mediaStream_});
        };
        this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
          if (event.data.size > 0) {
            this.chunks.push(event.data);
          };
        };
        this.mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
          track.stop();
          this.mediaStream_.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
          this.mediaStream_.removeTrack(track);
          console.log(`Completed recording ${this.utterance.text}`, this.chunks);
          resolve(this);
        }
        this.mediaRecorder.start();
        this.utterance.onstart = () => {
          console.log(`Starting recording SpeechSynthesisUtterance ${this.utterance.text}`);
        }
        this.utterance.onend = () => {
          this.mediaRecorder.stop();
          console.log(`Ending recording SpeechSynthesisUtterance ${this.utterance.text}`);
        }
        this.speechSynthesis.speak(this.utterance);
      }));
  }
  blob() {
    if (!this.chunks.length) throw new Error("no data to return");
    return Promise.resolve({
      tts: this,
      data: this.chunks.length === 1 ? this.chunks[0] : new Blob(this.chunks, {
        type: this.mimeType
      })
    });
  }
  arrayBuffer(blob) {
    if (!this.chunks.length) throw new Error("no data to return");
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const reader = new FileReader;
      reader.onload = e => resolve(({
        tts: this,
        data: reader.result
      }));
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob ? new Blob(blob, {
        type: blob.type
      }) : this.chunks.length === 1 ? this.chunks[0] : new Blob(this.chunks, {
        type: this.mimeType
      }));
    });
  }
  audioBuffer() {
    if (!this.chunks.length) throw new Error("no data to return");
    return this.arrayBuffer()
      .then(ab => this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(ab))
      .then(buffer => ({
        tts: this,
        data: buffer
      }))
  }
  mediaSource() {
    if (!this.chunks.length) throw new Error("no data to return");
    return this.arrayBuffer()
      .then(({
        data: ab
      }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.mediaSource_.onsourceended = () => resolve({
          tts: this,
          data: this.mediaSource_
        });
        this.mediaSource_.onsourceopen = () => {
          if (MediaSource.isTypeSupported(this.mimeType)) {
            const sourceBuffer = this.mediaSource_.addSourceBuffer(this.mimeType);
            sourceBuffer.mode = "sequence"
            sourceBuffer.onupdateend = () =>
              this.mediaSource_.endOfStream();
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(ab);
          } else {
            reject(`${this.mimeType} is not supported`)
          }
        }
        this.audioNode.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.mediaSource_);
      }));
  }
  readableStream({size = 1024, controllerOptions = {}, rsOptions = {}}) {
    if (!this.chunks.length) throw new Error("no data to return");
    const src = this.chunks.slice(0);
    const chunk = size;
    return Promise.resolve({
      tts: this,
      data: new ReadableStream(controllerOptions || {
        start(controller) {
            console.log(src.length);
            controller.enqueue(src.splice(0, chunk))
          },
          pull(controller) {
            if (src.length = 0) controller.close();
            controller.enqueue(src.splice(0, chunk));
          }
      }, rsOptions)
    });
  }
}
```

Usage

```
let ttsRecorder = new SpeechSynthesisRecorder({
   text: "The revolution will not be televised", 
   utternanceOptions: {
     voice: "english-us espeak",
     lang: "en-US",
     pitch: .75,
     rate: 1
   }
 });

 // ArrayBuffer
 ttsRecorder.start()
 // `tts` : `SpeechSynthesisRecorder` instance, `data` : audio as `dataType` or method call result
 .then(tts => tts.arrayBuffer())
 .then(({tts, data}) => {
   // do stuff with `ArrayBuffer`, `AudioBuffer`, `Blob`,
   // `MediaSource`, `MediaStream`, `ReadableStream`
   // `data` : `ArrayBuffer`
   tts.audioNode.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {type:tts.mimeType}));
   tts.audioNode.title = tts.utterance.text;
   tts.audioNode.onloadedmetadata = () => {
     console.log(tts.audioNode.duration);
     tts.audioNode.play();
   }
 })
 // AudioBuffer     
 ttsRecorder.start()
 .then(tts => tts.audioBuffer())
 .then(({tts, data}) => {
   // `data` : `AudioBuffer`
   let source = tts.audioContext.createBufferSource();
   source.buffer = data;
   source.connect(tts.audioContext.destination);
   source.start()
 })
 // Blob
 ttsRecorder.start()
 .then(tts => tts.blob())
 .then(({tts, data}) => {
   // `data` : `Blob`
   tts.audioNode.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   tts.audioNode.title = tts.utterance.text;
   tts.audioNode.onloadedmetadata = () => {
     console.log(tts.audioNode.duration);
     tts.audioNode.play();
   }
 })
 // ReadableStream
 ttsRecorder.start()
 .then(tts => tts.readableStream())
 .then(({tts, data}) => {
   // `data` : `ReadableStream`
   console.log(tts, data);
   data.getReader().read().then(({value, done}) => {
     tts.audioNode.src = URL.createObjectURL(value[0]);
     tts.audioNode.title = tts.utterance.text;
     tts.audioNode.onloadedmetadata = () => {
       console.log(tts.audioNode.duration);
       tts.audioNode.play();
     }
   })
 })
 // MediaSource
 ttsRecorder.start()
 .then(tts => tts.mediaSource())
 .then(({tts, data}) => {
   console.log(tts, data);
   // `data` : `MediaSource`
   tts.audioNode.srcObj = data;
   tts.audioNode.title = tts.utterance.text;
   tts.audioNode.onloadedmetadata = () => {
     console.log(tts.audioNode.duration);
     tts.audioNode.play();
   }
 })
 // MediaStream
 let ttsRecorder = new SpeechSynthesisRecorder({
   text: "The revolution will not be televised", 
   utternanceOptions: {
     voice: "english-us espeak",
     lang: "en-US",
     pitch: .75,
     rate: 1
   }, 
   dataType:"mediaStream"
 });
 ttsRecorder.start()
 .then(({tts, data}) => {
   // `data` : `MediaStream`
   // do stuff with active `MediaStream`
 })
 .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7Y2ifjRK5K9YGwT9G8nn?p=preview)

Comment: This is really awesome, you should put it in a npm  module

Comment: @YerkoPalma Have no experience creating an npm module. Feel free to take on the project; will contribute if able.

Comment: Hi @guest271314, isn't this recording the user's mic - and not the actual synthesized speech? Is that what you intended?

Comment: Thanks for this great example. I'm not sure if it is currently working in the latest Chrome (non beta). I have forked here to try it. I can see the audio player, but with no audio file in: https://jsfiddle.net/k1q07rsy/

Comment: @RonenRabinovici Yes, the original code at answer did record the device microphone. The original code is a workaround for the requirement to record speech synthesis by default at modern browsers. Updated code to set  `"audioouput"` as device to record https://github.com/guest271314/SpeechSynthesisRecorder/commit/87be7b9d39b034137fd79876e84050449887880f

Comment: @loretoparisi See updated code which sets media device to record to `"audiooutput"` https://plnkr.co/edit/PmpCSJ9GtVCXDhnOqn3D?p=preview

Comment: @guest271314, I used the code at https://plnkr.co/edit/PmpCSJ9GtVCXDhnOqn3D?p=preview but it still recorded from my microphone.

Comment: This doesn't record speaker output. I tried capturing tab audio using chrome extension but still failed. It seems speechSynthesis is not using HTMLmediaElement for audio hence we shall not be able to capture at tab/browser level. The audiooutput mentioned above returns "default " for both mic and speaker since there is no way to set "kind" field while setting constraints in getUsermedia, it always captures "mic". Let me know in case more details required.

Comment: Confirming that it records from microphone rather than speech synthesis - at least in Chrome 84.

Answer (score 4):

This is an updated code from previous answer which works in Chrome 96:

- make sure to select "Share system audio" checkbox in "Choose what to share" window
- won't run via SO code snippet (save to demo.html)

```html
<script>
(async () => {
const text = "The revolution will not be televised";

const blob = await new Promise(async resolve => {
    console.log("picking system audio");
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video:true, audio:true});
    const track = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
    if(!track)
        throw "System audio not available";
    
    stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    
    const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
    mediaStream.addTrack(track);
    
    const chunks = [];
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {bitsPerSecond:128000});
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
        if (event.data.size > 0)
            chunks.push(event.data);
    }
    mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        mediaStream.removeTrack(track);
        resolve(new Blob(chunks));
    }
    mediaRecorder.start();
    
    const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
    utterance.onend = () => mediaRecorder.stop();
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
    console.log("speaking...");
});
console.log("audio available", blob);

const player = new Audio();
player.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
player.autoplay = true;
player.controls = true;

})()
</script>
```

Comment: Feature request: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1291146

Comment: Remember to select entire screen to see the "Share system audio" checkbox.

Comment: FYI Chromium finally supports capturing monitor devices on Linux https://gist.github.com/guest271314/baaa0b8d4b034ff4e9352af4f2bbf42c. That means all system audio. Still no way per any Web API to capture only speechSynthesis.speak() output. Wrkaround have to be used.