# Can I add my own voice to TTS and can generate the paragraph with my own voice?

Tags: text-to-speech

Can I add the dictionary of my own voice for text to speech application? If it possible which development language would be best to develop such a this kind of application 
There are several online tool for text to speech but they have there own voices. I have to develop same like that application.please suggest me how I can go ahead with my concept .

Comment: Are you using native `window.speechSynthesis` for the text-to-speech application?

Comment: No I'm thinking to develop new application for that, but if it possible using windows speech synthesis then I can go through that

Comment: I have to also save that speech for further use

Comment: This Question/Answer should address that topic of recording and saving the generated audio result of `window.speechSynthesis.speak()` call [How to capture generated audio from window.speechSynthesis.speak() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003548/how-to-capture-generated-audio-from-window-speechsynthesis-speak-call); using `meSpeak.js` and other approaches [How to create or convert text to audio at chromium browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346410/how-to-create-or-convert-text-to-audio-at-chromium-browser)

Comment: Technically, yes, you can record your own voice and create a dictionary of key, value pairs reflecting the word and the audio file of the voice for that word. That would encompass essentially using the approaches at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346410/how-to-create-or-convert-text-to-audio-at-chromium-browser

Comment: Is it possible to add my own dictionary so that I can get the output with my voice . The input text will be anything such as it me will be one document

Comment: What would be the process to add the dictionary of my voice? Can you pls give some small basic idea

Comment: Yes. Record your voice for each word that you want the application to render as audio. Create an object of key, value pairs reflecting the word (property) and value (`data URL` or path to audio resource).

Comment: Need to record only alphabet A to Z or whole dictionary which has N number of words

Comment: _"Need to record only alphabet A to Z or whole dictionary which has N number of words "_ Yes, that is possible. In fact, that is one of the motivations for composing [SpeechSynthesisRecorder](https://github.com/guest271314/SpeechSynthesisRecorder), see [Re: MediaStream, ArrayBuffer, Blob audio result from speak() for recording?](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2017Jul/0004.html)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can build your voice with open source software like [Festival](http://festvox.org/bsv/) or [Openmary](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki/VoiceImportToolsTutorial). You will need a carefully prepared recording of your voice for about 1 hour

There are also commercial services which allows you to build a custom voice, for example [Cereproc](https://www.cereproc.com/en/products/cerevoiceme)

Update 2019: These days you can use modern neural network toolkits see [Nvidia Tactoron2](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2) and [Realtime Voice Cloning](https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning)

Answer (score -5):

You can record your voice for each word that you want the application to render as audio. Create an object of key, value pairs reflecting the word (property) and value (`data URL` or path to audio resource).

```
const voices = { 
                        // or path to static file
                 hello: "data:audio/ogg,/* base64 string of your voice */" 
               }

_speak("hello") // output audio, that is, your voice
```

Comment: Okay I'll try this method. thank you so much for your quick reply thank a lot .

Comment: this is highly inefficient and should never be done