# Offline Polish TextToSpeech in Linux

Tags: text-to-speech, polish

I already found and tried **espeak**/**espeak-ng** and **espeak** with **mbrola** but speech quality is less what desirable.

I aware about **Festival** and **Flite** engines but unable to find any Polish voice for them.

Comment: You can add the voice yourself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121645/can-i-add-my-own-voice-to-tts-and-can-generate-the-paragraph-with-my-own-voice

Comment: Thank you, but probably this not an option in my case.