# html js voice recorder not working in django python implementation

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, heroku

i have tried to implement a django application wherein the user can record a voice message pass it ti watson api and receive back the transcribed data and show the result to the user on a separate page. The recorder is not working as i am not able to save the file also what changes should be made if i want to deploy the application to heroku and have the voice recording saved there and then pass that audio file to watson api?

Code:

STT/STT/settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'my-secret-key'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'record',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'STT.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'STT.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)

WATSON_USERNAME = 'watson-username'
WATSON_PASSWORD = 'watson-password'
WATSON_ENDPOINT = 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize'
WATSON_DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
'continuous': True,
'timestamps': True,
'word_confidence': True,
}
WATSON_DEFAULT_HEADERS = {
'content-type': 'audio/wav'
}
```

STT/STT/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^record/', include('record.urls')),
]
```

STT/STT/wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "STT.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

STT/record/static/record/img/mic128.png:image file

STT/record/static/record/img/save.svg:image file

STT/record/static/record/js/recorderjs/recorder.js:

```
(function(window){

  var WORKER_PATH = 'js/recorderjs/recorderWorker.js';

  var Recorder = function(source, cfg){
    var config = cfg || {};
    var bufferLen = config.bufferLen || 4096;
    this.context = source.context;
    if(!this.context.createScriptProcessor){
       this.node = this.context.createJavaScriptNode(bufferLen, 2, 2);
    } else {
       this.node = this.context.createScriptProcessor(bufferLen, 2, 2);
    }

    var worker = new Worker(config.workerPath || WORKER_PATH);
    worker.postMessage({
      command: 'init',
      config: {
        sampleRate: this.context.sampleRate
      }
    });
    var recording = false,
      currCallback;

    this.node.onaudioprocess = function(e){
      if (!recording) return;
      worker.postMessage({
        command: 'record',
        buffer: [
          e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0),
          e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1)
        ]
      });
    }

    this.configure = function(cfg){
      for (var prop in cfg){
        if (cfg.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
          config[prop] = cfg[prop];
        }
      }
    }

    this.record = function(){
      recording = true;
    }

    this.stop = function(){
      recording = false;
    }

    this.clear = function(){
      worker.postMessage({ command: 'clear' });
    }

    this.getBuffers = function(cb) {
      currCallback = cb || config.callback;
      worker.postMessage({ command: 'getBuffers' })
    }

    this.exportWAV = function(cb, type){
      currCallback = cb || config.callback;
      type = type || config.type || 'audio/wav';
      if (!currCallback) throw new Error('Callback not set');
      worker.postMessage({
        command: 'exportWAV',
        type: type
      });
    }

    this.exportMonoWAV = function(cb, type){
      currCallback = cb || config.callback;
      type = type || config.type || 'audio/wav';
      if (!currCallback) throw new Error('Callback not set');
      worker.postMessage({
        command: 'exportMonoWAV',
        type: type
      });
    }

    worker.onmessage = function(e){
      var blob = e.data;
      currCallback(blob);
    }

    source.connect(this.node);
    this.node.connect(this.context.destination);   // if the script node is not connected to an output the "onaudioprocess" event is not triggered in chrome.
  };

  Recorder.setupDownload = function(blob, filename){
    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
    var link = document.getElementById("save");
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename || 'output.wav';
  }

  window.Recorder = Recorder;

})(window);
```

STT/record/static/record/js/recorderjs/recorderWorker.js:

```
  var recLength = 0,
  recBuffersL = [],
  recBuffersR = [],
  sampleRate;

this.onmessage = function(e){
  switch(e.data.command){
    case 'init':
      init(e.data.config);
      break;
    case 'record':
      record(e.data.buffer);
      break;
    case 'exportWAV':
      exportWAV(e.data.type);
      break;
    case 'exportMonoWAV':
      exportMonoWAV(e.data.type);
      break;
    case 'getBuffers':
      getBuffers();
      break;
    case 'clear':
      clear();
      break;
  }
};

function init(config){
  sampleRate = config.sampleRate;
}

function record(inputBuffer){
  recBuffersL.push(inputBuffer[0]);
  recBuffersR.push(inputBuffer[1]);
  recLength += inputBuffer[0].length;
}

function exportWAV(type){
  var bufferL = mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength);
  var bufferR = mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength);
  var interleaved = interleave(bufferL, bufferR);
  var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
  var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: type });

  this.postMessage(audioBlob);
}

function exportMonoWAV(type){
  var bufferL = mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength);
  var dataview = encodeWAV(bufferL, true);
  var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: type });

  this.postMessage(audioBlob);
}

function getBuffers() {
  var buffers = [];
  buffers.push( mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength) );
  buffers.push( mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength) );
  this.postMessage(buffers);
}

function clear(){
  recLength = 0;
  recBuffersL = [];
  recBuffersR = [];
}

function mergeBuffers(recBuffers, recLength){
  var result = new Float32Array(recLength);
  var offset = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < recBuffers.length; i++){
    result.set(recBuffers[i], offset);
    offset += recBuffers[i].length;
  }
  return result;
}

function interleave(inputL, inputR){
  var length = inputL.length + inputR.length;
  var result = new Float32Array(length);

  var index = 0,
    inputIndex = 0;

  while (index < length){
    result[index++] = inputL[inputIndex];
    result[index++] = inputR[inputIndex];
    inputIndex++;
  }
  return result;
}

function floatTo16BitPCM(output, offset, input){
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset+=2){
    var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
    output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF, true);
  }
}

function writeString(view, offset, string){
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
  }
}

function encodeWAV(samples, mono){
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
  var view = new DataView(buffer);

  /* RIFF identifier */
  writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
  /* file length */
  view.setUint32(4, 32 + samples.length * 2, true);
  /* RIFF type */
  writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
  /* format chunk identifier */
  writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
  /* format chunk length */
  view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
  /* sample format (raw) */
  view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
  /* channel count */
  view.setUint16(22, mono?1:2, true);
  /* sample rate */
  view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
  /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
  view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
  /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
  view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
  /* bits per sample */
  view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
  /* data chunk identifier */
  writeString(view, 36, 'data');
  /* data chunk length */
  view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

  floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

  return view;
}
```

STT/record/static/record/js/audiodisplay.js:

```
    function drawBuffer( width, height, context, data ) {
    var step = Math.ceil( data.length / width );
    var amp = height / 2;
    context.fillStyle = "silver";
    context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    for(var i=0; i < width; i++){
        var min = 1.0;
        var max = -1.0;
        for (j=0; j<step; j++) {
            var datum = data[(i*step)+j];
            if (datum < min)
                min = datum;
            if (datum > max)
                max = datum;
        }
        context.fillRect(i,(1+min)*amp,1,Math.max(1,(max-min)*amp));
    }
}
```

STT/record/static/record/js/main.js:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var audioInput = null,
    realAudioInput = null,
    inputPoint = null,
    audioRecorder = null;
var rafID = null;
var analyserContext = null;
var canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
var recIndex = 0;

/* TODO:

- offer mono option
- "Monitor input" switch
*/

function saveAudio() {
    audioRecorder.exportWAV( doneEncoding );
    // could get mono instead by saying
    // audioRecorder.exportMonoWAV( doneEncoding );
}

function gotBuffers( buffers ) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "wavedisplay" );

    drawBuffer( canvas.width, canvas.height, canvas.getContext('2d'), buffers[0] );

    // the ONLY time gotBuffers is called is right after a new recording is completed -
    // so here's where we should set up the download.
    audioRecorder.exportWAV( doneEncoding );
}

function doneEncoding( blob ) {
    Recorder.setupDownload( blob, "myRecording" + ((recIndex<10)?"0":"") + recIndex + ".wav" );
    recIndex++;
}

function toggleRecording( e ) {
    if (e.classList.contains("recording")) {
        // stop recording
        audioRecorder.stop();
        e.classList.remove("recording");
        audioRecorder.getBuffers( gotBuffers );
    } else {
        // start recording
        if (!audioRecorder)
            return;
        e.classList.add("recording");
        audioRecorder.clear();
        audioRecorder.record();
    }
}

function convertToMono( input ) {
    var splitter = audioContext.createChannelSplitter(2);
    var merger = audioContext.createChannelMerger(2);

    input.connect( splitter );
    splitter.connect( merger, 0, 0 );
    splitter.connect( merger, 0, 1 );
    return merger;
}

function cancelAnalyserUpdates() {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame( rafID );
    rafID = null;
}

function updateAnalysers(time) {
    if (!analyserContext) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("analyser");
        canvasWidth = canvas.width;
        canvasHeight = canvas.height;
        analyserContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    // analyzer draw code here
    {
        var SPACING = 3;
        var BAR_WIDTH = 1;
        var numBars = Math.round(canvasWidth / SPACING);
        var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyserNode.frequencyBinCount);

        analyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData);

        analyserContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        analyserContext.fillStyle = '#F6D565';
        analyserContext.lineCap = 'round';
        var multiplier = analyserNode.frequencyBinCount / numBars;

        // Draw rectangle for each frequency bin.
        for (var i = 0; i < numBars; ++i) {
            var magnitude = 0;
            var offset = Math.floor( i * multiplier );
            // gotta sum/average the block, or we miss narrow-bandwidth spikes
            for (var j = 0; j< multiplier; j++)
                magnitude += freqByteData[offset + j];
            magnitude = magnitude / multiplier;
            var magnitude2 = freqByteData[i * multiplier];
            analyserContext.fillStyle = "hsl( " + Math.round((i*360)/numBars) + ", 100%, 50%)";
            analyserContext.fillRect(i * SPACING, canvasHeight, BAR_WIDTH, -magnitude);
        }
    }

    rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updateAnalysers );
}

function toggleMono() {
    if (audioInput != realAudioInput) {
        audioInput.disconnect();
        realAudioInput.disconnect();
        audioInput = realAudioInput;
    } else {
        realAudioInput.disconnect();
        audioInput = convertToMono( realAudioInput );
    }

    audioInput.connect(inputPoint);
}

function gotStream(stream) {
    inputPoint = audioContext.createGain();

    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    realAudioInput = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    audioInput = realAudioInput;
    audioInput.connect(inputPoint);

//    audioInput = convertToMono( input );

    analyserNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyserNode.fftSize = 2048;
    inputPoint.connect( analyserNode );

    audioRecorder = new Recorder( inputPoint );

    zeroGain = audioContext.createGain();
    zeroGain.gain.value = 0.0;
    inputPoint.connect( zeroGain );
    zeroGain.connect( audioContext.destination );
    updateAnalysers();
}

function initAudio() {
        if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
            navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        if (!navigator.cancelAnimationFrame)
            navigator.cancelAnimationFrame = navigator.webkitCancelAnimationFrame || navigator.mozCancelAnimationFrame;
        if (!navigator.requestAnimationFrame)
            navigator.requestAnimationFrame = navigator.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || navigator.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

    navigator.getUserMedia(
        {
            "audio": {
                "mandatory": {
                    "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                    "googAutoGainControl": "false",
                    "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                    "googHighpassFilter": "false"
                },
                "optional": []
            }
        }, gotStream, function(e) {
            alert('Error getting audio');
            console.log(e);
        });
}

window.addEventListener('load', initAudio );
```

STT/record/static/record/style.css:

```
html { overflow: hidden; }
body {
    font: 14pt Arial, sans-serif;
    background: lightgrey;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0;
}
canvas {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #202020;
    width: 95%;
    height: 45%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px blue;
}
#controls {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}
#record { height: 15vh; }
#record.recording {
    background: red;
}
#save, #save img { height: 10vh; }
#save { opacity: 0.25;}
#save[download] { opacity: 1;}
#viz {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
@media (orientation: landscape) {
    body { flex-direction: row;}
    #controls { flex-direction: column; height: 100%; width: 10%;}
    #viz { height: 100%; width: 90%;}
}
```

STT/record/templates/record/index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Audio Recorder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'record/style.css' %}"/>
    <script src="{% static 'record/js/audiodisplay.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'record/js/recorderjs/recorder.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'record/js/main.js' %}"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="viz">
        <canvas id="analyser" width="1024" height="500"></canvas>
        <canvas id="wavedisplay" width="1024" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
        <img id="record" src="{% static 'record/img/mic128.png' %}" onclick="toggleRecording(this);">
        <a id="save" href="#"><img src="{% static 'record/img/save.svg' %}"></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

STT/record/apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class RecordConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'record'
```

STT/record/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

STT/record/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from pydub import AudioSegment
from glob import glob
from math import ceil
from os.path import basename, splitext, exists
import json
import requests
import csv
from STT.settings import WATSON_USERNAME, WATSON_PASSWORD, WATSON_ENDPOINT, WATSON_DEFAULT_PARAMS, \
    WATSON_DEFAULT_HEADERS


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'record/index.html')

# POST

# via: http://www.propublica.org/podcast/item/how-a-reporter-pierced-the-hype-behind-theranos/
DOWNLOAD_URL = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/247345268/download?client_id=cUa40O3Jg3Emvp6Tv4U6ymYYO50NUGpJ'
AUDIO_FILENAME = 'podcast.mp3'
AUDIO_SEGMENT_SECONDS = 300

if not exists(AUDIO_FILENAME):
    print("Downloading from", DOWNLOAD_URL)
    resp = requests.get(DOWNLOAD_URL)

    with open(AUDIO_FILENAME, 'wb') as w:
        w.write(resp.content)
        print("Wrote audio file to", AUDIO_FILENAME)

    # convert to WAV
    audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(AUDIO_FILENAME)
    xs = 0
    while xs < audio.duration_seconds:
        ys = min(xs + AUDIO_SEGMENT_SECONDS, ceil(audio.duration_seconds))
        fname = str(xs).rjust(5, '0') + '-' + str(ys).rjust(5, '0') + '.wav'
        audio[xs * 1000:ys * 1000].export(fname, format='wav')
        print("Saved", fname)
        xs = ys


# Transcribe each WAV to Watson
for fname in glob("*.wav"):
    # Download watson's response
    tname = splitext(basename(fname))[0] + '.json'
    if exists(tname):
        print("Already transcribed", tname)
    else:
        print("Transcribing", fname)
        with open(fname, 'rb') as r:
            watson_response = requests.post(
                WATSON_ENDPOINT,
                data=r,
                auth=(WATSON_USERNAME, WATSON_PASSWORD),
                params=WATSON_DEFAULT_PARAMS,
                headers=WATSON_DEFAULT_HEADERS,
                stream=False
            )
            with open(tname, 'w') as w:
                w.write(watson_response.text)
                print("Wrote transcript to", tname)


# Print out the raw transcript and word csv
rawfile = open("raw.txt", "w")
wordsfile = open("words.csv", "w")
csvfile = csv.writer(wordsfile)
csvfile.writerow(['word', 'confidence', 'start', 'end'])

for fname in sorted(glob("*.json")):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        results = json.load(f)['results']
        for linenum, result in enumerate(results):  # each result is a  line
            if result.get('alternatives'):  # each result may have many alternatives
                # just pick best alternative
                lineobj = result.get('alternatives')[0]
                # rawfile.writeline(lineobj['transcript'])
                word_timestamps = lineobj['timestamps']
                if word_timestamps:
                    rawfile.write(lineobj['transcript'] + "\n")

                    word_confidences = lineobj['word_confidence']
                    for idx, wordts in enumerate(word_timestamps):
                        txt, tstart, tend = wordts
                        confidence = round(100 * word_confidences[idx][1])
                        csvfile.writerow([txt, confidence, tstart, tend])

rawfile.close()
wordsfile.close()
```

In the views.py file i need to be able to print the rawfile as text onto a new HTML result page which should open after the user has recorded the message and uploaded it to Watson.

Comment: You can use [`SpeechRecognition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/SpeechRecognition), see also [How to create or convert text to audio at chromium browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346410/how-to-create-or-convert-text-to-audio-at-chromium-browser), [How to capture generated audio from window.speechSynthesis.speak() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003548/how-to-capture-generated-audio-from-window-speechsynthesis-speak-call)