# How to implement the capture audio/download feature for the generated Speech Audio from Web Speech API (window.speechSynthesis.speak()) call?

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech, webspeech-api

I want to be able to download the (Text to Speech) audio that is generated when we make window.speechSynthesis.speak() call!

Below mentioned is one of the previous posts which discusses the same issue:-

[How to capture generated audio from window.speechSynthesis.speak() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003548/how-to-capture-generated-audio-from-window-speechsynthesis-speak-call)

But, the answer gives the solution to record the user mic and video camera using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(). None of the answers show how to download the generated audio.

Comment: Should it be a client/browser-only solution or can a server be involved?

Comment: Well, I am looking for a client browser solution. But, I am open for other suggestions too! Thanks!