# How to capture the output from speechSynthesis.speak() so that I can use that output in audio.src to create a audiovisualizer using javascript?

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

[speechSynthesis.speak()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkjR9.jpg)
How to connect speechSynthesis.speak() to audio.src

Comment: Welcome! This question needs more detail. What have you tried? When it (presumably) didn't work, what failed? In what context are you running this?

Comment: This seem to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003548/how-to-capture-generated-audio-from-window-speechsynthesis-speak-call