# Selecting speech synthesis audio output device

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium, webapi

You can read about Speech Synthesis Web-API [[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis), [[2]](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#tts-section), is supported to some extent by several browsers [[3]](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_speechsynthesis)

Here is a basic example

```js
let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(
  "I want to get this text uttered (on a specific device)"
);
utterance.lang = 'en';
speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```

Is it possible to specify the audio output where it will play?

(it could use a chromium extension if necessary)

Comment: You may want to look at the code for the Chrome extension [AudioPick](https://github.com/rain-fighters/AudioPick) to understand how they do it.

Comment: But speech synthesis does add an `audio` or `video` element to the document, so AudioPick won't work. Either way, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: There's no easy way to achieve what you want as the Web SpeechSynthesis API doesn't provide any facilities to select the output sound device. There's [a discussion](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-output/issues/102) on GitHub regarding this issue. Besides, you can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003548/how-to-capture-generated-audio-from-window-speechsynthesis-speak-call) and check if the solution works for your situation.

Comment: Yes, a streamed version of the solution from the post you mentioned might work for me, since I only need to use this to automate some tests. Not so elegant but good enough :)