# How to change UserAgent and IP address of http request in android?

Tags: android, http, ip, user-agent

I have Android application uses Google TTS over this link http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=en&q=how%20are%20you
But recently when my app requests above link it redirected to a web page says "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot".

I think I have to use proxy to change request IP address and user agent every time I use the link.
So how can I change them?

Comment: Built-in TTS doesn't support most languages

Comment: `User-Agent` is just a header from your networking lib, you can set what you want.

Comment: @Laurent Meyer You're right, But I need to change IP address also

Comment: No I'd try with a Desktop Chrome User Agent and I think it could work

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31791632/1986871) which is an update to the original Google TTS solution. You need to set the `Referer` and `User-Agent` headers before you use that URL. You didn't tell us *how* you were using the URL. If you just have a link to open a `WebView`, I don't think there's anything you can do. However, if you're using `MediaPlayer` to download/play audio, see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31792681/1986871) which works on everything except 4.X (which is why I asked the question). You shouldn't be changing the `IP` at all, leave that one alone.