# How to use Google Text to Speech API?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I am planning on getting an API key and use the Speech services provided by Google. But I can't find any documentation on how to use the text to speech api of Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is not true anymore, Google does offer a [Text-to-Speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/) API now, or to be more specific, Google Cloud does.
Here is a Quickstart [guide](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol).

Answer (score 2):

simple rules for work this :

q = for pass your language encode. 
tl = for pass your language name

simple try this :

https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%20%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%82%20%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BF+&tl=bn&client=tw-ob

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't actually have an official Text-to-speech API. You can use their google translate service to get some results, but again it's not officially supported so no docs are available as far as I know.

Google has Cloud Speech API, which does the opposite thing, i.e converts speech to text. It seems people often confuse the two, thinking you can use cloud speech for text-to-speech.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893175/google-text-to-speech-api) might be a good starting point on how to use google translate for text-to-speech. Although personally I would try and find an API which is designed for that task.